# Can chain link fence rail be used as electrical conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I just removed a chain link fence and had the idea to reuse the rail pipe as underground electrical conduit. I already have part of a trench dug and was planning to buy some conduit, but if I could reuse this metal pipe, then I could save some money. The pipe outside diameter is 1.25 inches and inside diameter is 1 inch. I assume that you can get fittings for this size pipe. Is there anything in the electrical codes that would prevent me from reusing this chain link fence rail pipe as underground electrical conduit?

Comment: Is it UL approved?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg I don’t know what that means.

Comment: Underwriters Laboratories  has to approve items for electrical use. If an item it approved, it will be stamped "UL" or something similar.

Comment: "NEC 110.3(B) Installation and Use. Listed or labeled equipment shall be installed and used in accordance with any instructions included in the listing or labeling."  So a UL stamp means only approved as submitted and tested.

Comment: Just curious, how will an electrical inspector tell the difference between “normal” conduit and the galvanized fence rail?

Comment: One electrical use for non electrical pipe is to put sleeves in concrete.  If you need a hole through a wall for a conduit, you can embed pretty much any kind of pipe just to produce a hole through the concrete.  There's also some chance you could convince an inspector it was mechanical protection for a small but still rated for direct burial cable or pipe inside, but you'd probably have to ground the whole length and it would not remotely be worth the trouble.

Comment: To be clear I'm talking about limited thickness indoor walls.  One note is there may be some concern of bonding with dissimilar metals, and another that you may need armor if the inside surface is rough.  I would imagine the poles are concrete compatible though and rubber coated armored cable or conduit deals with bonding concerns if they exist.  Pretty specific use, but by the time you're done you could spend more than if you'd just embedded ENT or EMT.

Comment: How to tell difference: Other than just recognizing the size is just not quite right the biggest tell tale will be fittings, you can't thread thinwall pipe and threadless connectors won't hold securely to the pipe.

Answer (score 7):

Electrical conduit is ***similar*** to pipe, but there are important differences, such as requirements for the inside to be smooth so it won't damage wires.

In short, no. Use actual electrical conduit.

Comment: what about using the pipe to run smurf tubing inside or similar?

Comment: And at the ends of the pipe, what: Smurf tube in the ground? The rodents are going to love that... ENT is not rated for burial (unless perhaps if you are pouring concrete - I know it is used in poured concrete walls.) "Article 362 of the 2002 National Electrical Code, Uses not Permitted, prohibits ENT from being direct buried."  "ENT does not have UV inhibitors and should not be used outdoors where exposed to the sun. " Quotes from: https://carlonsales.com/techinfo/faqs/FAQ-ENT.pdf